# RxJS withLatestFrom doest not emit value if the target has a share operator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

```
const a$ = new BehaviorSubject(['a']).pipe(
    // op.share() does not have share
);

a$.subscribe((a) => {
    console.log('a$', a)
})

const b$ = new BehaviorSubject([1]);
const c$ = b$.pipe(
    op.withLatestFrom(a$)
)
c$.subscribe(c => {
    console.log('c$ test', c) // you can find logs in console
})
```

but if I add a share to a$, subscription of c fail to run.

```
const a$ = new BehaviorSubject(['a']).pipe(
    op.share()
);

a$.subscribe((a) => {
    console.log('a$', a)
})

const b$ = new BehaviorSubject([1]);
const c$ = b$.pipe(
    op.withLatestFrom(a$)
)
c$.subscribe(c => {
    console.log('c$ test', c) // logs here cannot be found in console
})
```

I cannot understand why this happened. and I do need a$ to be shared. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

`share` doesn't replay values to late subscribers, so you lose the replay functionality of your BehaviorSubject. The first subscription to `a$` triggers a subscribe to the BehaviorSubject and `share` forewards its value. When you subscribe a second time to `a$` `share` has already subscribed to the BehaviorSubject so it won't get its value again and, as `share` has no replay functionality, won't replay its value.

If your source is a BehaviorSubject and you don't use any other operators you don't need to share it.

If your source is acutally something else your can use `shareReplay(1)` instead of `share` to replay its latest value to late subscribers.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it does not work with `shareReplay(1)` or `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })`. If I remove the `shareReplay(...)` it is working as expected.